# Print String using DefaulTableModel GUI

Tags: java, swing

I have some problems printing Strings using the DefaulTableModel. Basically what I'm trying to do is running an operation with a For Loop, but instead of printing those values, i want the system to perform with an IF Statement a validation of the results, and print two strings according to the ranges.

Here's the code:

```
    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        String VIP, NoVIP;
            int n = 10;
        int m = 1513;
        int a = 19713;
        double x = 177963;
        int c = 1397;
        double r;
        int i;
            Object[] res = new Object[n]; 
                for(i=0;i< n;i++){
            r = (a*x+c)%m;
            x = r;
            r = r/m;                            
            res[i] = r;
                        if(r>=0.93){
                            dtm.addColumn("Results", VIP );                               
                            jTable1.setModel(dtm);
                        }else{
                            dtm.addColumn("Results", NoVIP);                                
                            jTable1.setModel(dtm);
                        }                            
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your problem and your code in greater detail.

Comment: You should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for faster help.

Comment: Ok. I'm currently using a formula that helps me to obtain Random Numbers(a formula that i saw in a class) (r = (a*x+c)%m; x = r; r = r/m;). The values i will get will be between 0 to 1. So the thing is that according to the if statement, the operation will be performed 10 times, but intead of printing those values on a jTable, i want the system to print from this condition (r>=0.93) a string that says if the client is VIp or Not.

Comment: There's no need to call `setModel()` in a loop.